# Unity: mesh.triangles = t; mesh.triangles == t returns false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural-generation

I'm making a program where a large and complicated mesh is procedurally generated. At first I generated a large number of smaller meshes, which works just fine, but then I decided to merge them together and some triangles got corrupted.
[image: Some triangles are very l o n g, when they absolutely shouldn't be]
After a bit of looking i managed to pinpoint the problem:

```
Debug.Log(fullTriangles == fullTriangles);
boxMesh.triangles = fullTriangles;
Debug.Log(boxMesh.triangles == fullTriangles);
```

[image: first log returns true, second log returns false]

This only occurs when I use the large mesh. For the many smaller meshes both debugs return true.

Here's a picture of the mesh. It loops on itself in many places, is in no way convex, has several floating islands,  and is in general very difficult from a rendering perspective.
[image: The mesh is a slight mess]

Other information that might matter:

- The many small meshes in the large mesh do not share any verticies in the large mesh, but some verticies have the same positions
- Each small mesh is made of one or several triangles, that do share verticies
- The small meshes are not submeshes

Why does this happend, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your mesh has too many vertices, take a look at [mesh index format](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html).

To avoid this problem, you could either run a [mesh welder](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1382854/welding-vertices-at-runtime.html), or batch smaller meshes together. You could also merge smaller meshes into a bigger one, but keeping count of the merged mesh number of vertices. If it exceeds the vertex count limit, create another merged mesh (and so on).

As a side note, keep in mind that comparing arrays with " == " will not compare the values in the array, but the arrays references. You could use [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netcore-3.1), or run a simple for loop.

Comment: Turns out the mesh had 67272 verticies. Changing the mesh index format fixed it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Nice to hear! Glad I could help.